# Python SQLite Data inserted into table disappearing?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

So this is confusing the hell out of me, and the title doesn't really explain it properly. I have a webpage which, when a user selects from a dropdown list makes an AJAX call to a url which is handled by flask. It first issues a call to `/teamSelected`, where my python scrapes some information about the football match between those two teams, puts it in an accordingly named table and returns.
After this, the second AJAX call is made to `/requestCommentary` where in python i then retrieve this data from the table and return it.

**Problem**:
When I first make the call to `/teamSelected`, I have code which drops the table if it exists. After which I check if the table exists (seems strange but dropping the table everytime its called is just me making sure the `if` part of the program is entered so I can test everything is working in there). After which if the table doesn't exist, it enters the `if` portion, where it creates the table, scrapes the data and stores it in the table. If I then try to print the contents of the table, it spits them out perfectly, despite telling me there exists only 1 row?
However if I remove the code at the start which drops the table, then try to print the contents, it prints nothing.

To me this makes very little sense. If the table doesnt exist, I make it, fill it with data and I can access it. However if I comment out the drop table statement, next call the table exists and isn't dropped, so I should be able to access it, but there's no longer data in there. If I were to guess, it's almost as if the table is made only for that that call, where it is then destroyed afterwards, so subsequent calls can't access it?

**/teamSelected** - Scrapes data, adds to database

```
@app.route("/teamSelected", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def new():
        try:
            connection = sqlite3.connect("commentary.db")
            cursor = connection.cursor()
        except:
            print("COULD NOT CONNECT TO DATABASE")            

        data = request.get_data() #gets data passed via AJAX call
        splitData = data.decode().replace("\"", "").split("__") #data contains different elements split up by "__"
        homeTeam = splitData[0]
        awayTeam = splitData[1]
        tableName = homeTeam + awayTeam + splitData[2] #unique table name

        cursor.execute("DROP TABLE if exists "+tableName) #drops table to ensure enters if statement
        cursor.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='"+tableName+"';")
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        number_of_rows = result[0]

        print("R O W S   " + str(number_of_rows)) #Always prints 0
        if(number_of_rows == 0):
            create_table_string = "create table if not exists '"+ tableName + "' (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, commentary TEXT, time TEXT)"
            cursor.execute(create_table_string)

            def scrapeInfo():
                     ...
                #scraping stuff
                     ...
                maxUpdate = 5
                updateNumber = 0

                while updateNumber < maxUpdate:
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO "+tableName+"(commentary, time) VALUES(?,?)", (commentaryUpdates[updateNumber], times[updateNumber]))
                    #inserts scraped data into table
                    updateNumber += 1

                cursor.execute("select * from " + tableName)
                rows = cursor.fetchall()
                for row in rows:
                    print(row)
                #THIS ^ works

                cursor.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='" + tableName + "';")
                result = cursor.fetchone()
                number_of_rows = result[0]
                print(number_of_rows)
                #This ^ prints 1 despite the above for loop printing 5 rows
                return jsonify("CLEAN")
            return scrapeInfo()

        #This is only hit if the table exists, meaning it doesn't enter 
        #the if statement, so this section is only hit when the drop table 
        #statement above is commented out. Here, this prints nothing, no idea why.
        cursor.execute("select * from " + tableName)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print(row)
```

**/RequestCommentary** - retrieves data from table

```
@app.route("/requestCommentary", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def getCommentary():

    data = request.get_data()
    splitData = data.decode().replace("\"", "").split("__")
    homeTeam = splitData[0]
    awayTeam = splitData[1]
    tableName = homeTeam + awayTeam + splitData[2]

    #Here I'm trying to retrieve the data from the table, but nothing is printed
    cursor.execute("select * from " + tableName)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
    return jsonify("CLEAN")
```

To recap, unexpected behaviour:

- Data is only retrieved from table if it is first dropped, then has data added
- If table already exists from previous call where data was added, new call retrieves no data
- `Number_of_rows` after insertion of the data prints 1 (could be relevant as should be printing 5)
- Separate route `/RequestCommentary` cannot access table regardless
- No exceptions being thrown

I could *really* use a hand on this, as I am completely stumped on what the issue is here and have been at this for hours.

After some more testing, I'm certain it's something to do with the scope of the tables being created. I'm not sure how or why, but I can only seem to access data I add to the table in that call, any data added from previous calls is non-existent, which makes me think somehow the tables data is local only to the call accessing it, and isn't global?

Comment: If your code is presented correctly then problem is with `return scrapeInfo()`, that line should be called within: `if(number_of_rows == 0):` block... Besides that - what about SQL injection?

Comment: Ah yeah apologies, i'll edit that now. In my code scrapeInfo is called from within the if statement. As for SQL injections, I'm just trying to get the code to actually work before I worry about security

Comment: Sure - no offence / just spotting ;) Other then that, I think number of tables, and number of rows in the table are messed. Please use two separate variables... maybe for clarification only. Also it would be good to have scrapInfo as separate function called from outside - that way it is easy to see what is passed there.

Comment: @MichałZaborowski No problem man, managed to figure it out, but appreaciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just managed to figure it out. I knew it was something to do with making local changes not being seen globally. After looking around I realised this is the exact problem I'd be having if I wasnt using `connection.commit()` to save the changes being made. I've added it now, and the changes being made can now be seen by all calls and is working properly.